# using CSS to replace a text link with a "Buy-It" button. Want a.class hidden but a.class:before to be visible. Not working in IE. Why?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, visibility, pseudo-element

I'm using CSS to replace a text link with a "Buy-It" button.  It works in FireFox but not in IE, and I can't see why it shouldn't work in both.

Here's the HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="..." 
        class="doclink">
    text_of_link 
    </a>
</p>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
/*  Replace the text link with a buy-it button  
*/
div.item-page p a.doclink      
    { display: block;  visibility:hidden;  }
div.item-page p a.doclink:before 
    {   content: "Buy Now!";  visibility:visible; 
        display: block;

        text-align: center; color: #ffffff; 
        font-weight: normal;  font-size:18px;  letter-spacing:2px;          
        font-style:italic;
        font-family:tahoma,helv,arial;
        background: #13357a;  border-radius: 5px;  padding:15px; 
        width: 150px;

        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 15px 6px; 
    }
div.item-page p a.doclink:after   /* to clear the float, if any  */ 
    { content: "";   
      display: block;    
      clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of IE? It's only support in IE8+: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Comment: Have you checked that if the underlying element is "visible", then the `:before` part can be hidden? I don't think so. Same for `display`. If the underlying element is `display: none`, I believe the `:before` part will be hidden no matter what its `display` property.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  

I was using MSIE 11.  

According to the standards, yes the pseudo element should be stylable independently from the element.

According to the Microsoft Developer Network description of MSIE's handing of the ::before, yes it should be independently stylable. 

Since posting, it's become clear that this is an IE bug.  In all other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc.) it works.  In both MSIE 10 & 11 it does not, despite MS's ::before specs.

Answer (score 0):

If CSS is not supported in your targeted browser, you can use JavaScript to achieve the same feature.

Here a simple example:

http://jsbin.com/carazahiguta/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    function init() {
      var elms = document.querySelectorAll('.doclink');
      for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
            var item = elms[i];
            item.innerHTML = 'Buy Now';   
      };

    }


  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<p>
    <a href="..." 
        class="doclink">
    text_of_link 
    </a>
</p>
  <p>
    <a href="..." 
        class="doclink">
    text_of_link 
    </a>
</p>
  <p>
    <a href="..." 
        class="doclink">
    text_of_link 
    </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you GibboK.  That's a good workaround.  

Can anybody advise me:  
Is it better to keep the CSS as is and add a browser test to the javascript so it is active only for IE?  

Or might I just as well forget the CSS, and leave the javascript to do it for every visitor?

Comment: I would use a JavaScript approach. You can solve the problem in an easier way and you do not need check for the browser type.